# Firebase web phone number authentication not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've been googling for 2 days for html and JavaScript code for adding firebase phone number authentication in my website.
I saw the firebaseui doing this job.
But it has their own form elements.
I haven't found any articles or videos showing "how to make Firebase web auth with phone number, without using Firebaseui/nodejs.
Is it really possible to do this with my own textbox and other buttons?
I had written a code for this and it's not working.
Please do a checkup or prefer any best articles, showing the exact thing I want.
The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Untitled</title>
      <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.6.2/firebase.js"></script>
      <script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "*****",
    authDomain: "********.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://********.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "*******",
    storageBucket: "*********.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "**********"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
            <script>
var phoneNumber = getPhoneNumberFromUserInput();
var appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
.then(function (confirmationResult) {
    alert('sms sent');
// SMS sent. Prompt user to type the code from the message, then sign the
// user in with confirmationResult.confirm(code).
window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
}).catch(function (error) {
// Error; SMS not sent
// ...
alert('sms not send');
});
      </script>
      <form>
      <input type="tel" id="number">
        <input type="number" id="otp_code">
        <input type="submit">
        </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please indent your code correctly. Further, why do you not want to use FirebaseUI?

Comment: I'm making a big form, where phone number input is needed. Also, I want to check whether the number  is their own or not.

Comment: I'm a newbie in Firebase. So, please help me on this 'intenting' thing

Comment: See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_(typesetting)) for more information on indentation.

Comment: Read it. But I'm totally confused.

Comment: You should add spaces whenever you open a tag. Otherwise your code is unreadable. Screw it, I'll do it.

Comment: It's been about 3 days. Anybody know the answer?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of examples including the Firebase GitHub sample quick start apps: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/auth/phone-invisible.html

Also check the official docs on this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth

Here is a quick snippet on signing in a user with phone number:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber("+xxxxxxxx", window.recaptchaVerifier)
  .then((confirmationResult) => {
    // At this point SMS is sent. Ask user for code.
    let code = window.prompt('Please enter the 6 digit code');
    return confirmationResult.confirm(code);
  })
  .then((result) {
    // User is now signed in and accessible via result.user.
  });
  .catch((error) => {
    // Error occurred.
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   # Try This Code. I have only add js/jquery code#
    <script>
  // Paste the config your copied earlier
   var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "############################",
    authDomain: "############################",
    databaseURL: "############################",
    projectId: "############################",
    storageBucket: "############################",
    messagingSenderId: "############################",
    appId: "############################",
    measurementId: "############################"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  // Create a Recaptcha verifier instance globally
  // Calls submitPhoneNumberAuth() when the captcha is verified
 //set size: "normal" to add recaptcha
  window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(
    "recaptcha-container",
    {
      size: "invisible",
      callback: function(response) {
        submitPhoneNumberAuth();
      }
    }
  );
  // This function runs when the 'sign-in-button' is clicked
  // Takes the value from the 'phoneNumber' input and sends SMS to that phone number
function submitPhoneNumberAuth() {
    $("#wait").css("display", "block");
    $("#sign-in-button").attr("disabled", true);
    var userPhone = document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value;
    if(userPhone.length != 11){
        $("#message").removeClass("alert-info");
        $("#message").addClass("alert-danger");
        $("#message").html("Please Insert 11 digit Phone Number!!!");
        $("#message").css("display", "block");
        $("#wait").css("display", "none");
        $("#sign-in-button").attr("disabled", false);
        return false;
    }
    var phoneNumber = "+88"+userPhone;
    //+88 only for bangladesh.Add your own country code
    var appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
      .then(function(confirmationResult) {
        document.getElementById('codeDiv').style.display='block'; 
        document.getElementById('getCodeButton').style.display='none';
        window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
        $("#message").html("Please check your inbox and insert code!!!");
        $("#message").css("display", "block");
        $("#wait").css("display", "none");
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        $("#sign-in-button").attr("disabled", false);
        $("#wait").css("display", "none");
        console.log(error.code);
        if(error.code == 'auth/invalid-phone-number'){
            $("#message").removeClass("alert-info");
            $("#message").addClass("alert-danger");
            $("#message").html("Invalid Phone Number!! Try Another Number!!!");
            $("#message").css("display", "block");
            document.getElementById('getCodeButton').style.display='block';
            document.getElementById('codeDiv').style.display='none';
        }
        else if(error.code == 'auth/too-many-requests'){
            $("#message").removeClass("alert-info");
            $("#message").addClass("alert-danger");
            $("#message").html("Too many request from this number. Try Another Number!!");
            $("#message").css("display", "block");
            document.getElementById('getCodeButton').style.display='block';
            document.getElementById('codeDiv').style.display='none';
        }

      });
  }
  // This function runs when the 'confirm-code' button is clicked
  // Takes the value from the 'code' input and submits the code to verify the phone number
  // Return a user object if the authentication was successful, and auth is complete
function submitPhoneNumberAuthCode() {
    $("#wait").css("display", "block");
    $('#confirm-code').attr("disabled", true);
    var code = document.getElementById("code").value;
    confirmationResult
      .confirm(code)
      .then(function(result) {
        var user = result.user;
        $("#wait").css("display", "block");
        $("#message").removeClass("alert-danger");
        $("#message").addClass("alert-info");
        $("#message").html("Thank you!!Code Matched!!");
        $("#message").css("display", "block");
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        $("#wait").css("display", "none");
        $('#confirm-code').attr("disabled", false);
        console.log(error);
        $("#message").removeClass("alert-info");
        $("#message").addClass("alert-danger");
        $("#message").html("Code Not Matched!!!");
        $("#message").css("display", "block");
      });
  }
  //This function runs everytime the auth state changes. Use to verify if the user is logged in
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
        //You are logged IN from firebase
        $("#message").removeClass("alert-danger");
        $("#message").addClass("alert-info");
        $("#message").html("Congratulations!!!Logging...");
        $("#message").css("display", "block");
        var phone = user.phoneNumber;
        firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
         ////You are logged Out from firebase
         console.log("Firebase Signout");
        }).catch(function(error) {
         console.log("Firebase Signout Problem!!");

        });
```

}

Comment: please add html